# editText parse double

Tags: android, debugging, android-edittext

I'm having difficulty identifying what is causing this app to crash.

When I comment out my lines to retrieve text from my editText box the app will not work.

If I simply set the circle to a defined radius in the program it looks fine.

Where I have lines commented out is where I suspect the problem may be. Thanks!

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener{


GoogleMap mMap;
Location myLocation;


//EditText length = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1); 


//String lengthString = length.getText().toString();



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

    if (mMap!= null) {

    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);


    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomBy(17));}





   Location myLocation;

  LocationManager locationmanager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
  Criteria cr = new Criteria();
  String provider = locationmanager.getBestProvider(cr, true);
  Location location = locationmanager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

  locationmanager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 200, 0, (LocationListener) this);

    }




@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

     mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng((new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()))));


     CircleOptions circleOptions = new CircleOptions()
    .center(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));




         // double bacons = Double.parseDouble(lengthString);

         // if (bacons >=0) {

      //double radi = bacons * 0.3048;
    //circleOptions.radius(radi); // In meters
    //circleOptions.fillColor(0xffff0000);
    //circleOptions.strokeWidth(0);
    //mMap.addCircle(circleOptions); 
        //  } else { 

        double radi = 20 * 0.3048;
        circleOptions.radius(radi); // In meters
        circleOptions.fillColor(0xffff0000);
        circleOptions.strokeWidth(0);

        mMap.addCircle(circleOptions); }
    //}
```

Ok this is what it does after doing the recommendations below. It now runs, but then suspends as soon as the map loads.

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener{


GoogleMap mMap;
Location myLocation;
EditText length;
String lengthString;




@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  length = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1); 


    lengthString = length.getText().toString();

     mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

    if (mMap!= null) {

    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);


    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomBy(17));}



 // Get back the mutable Circle

 Location myLocation;

 LocationManager locationmanager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
 Criteria cr = new Criteria();
 String provider = locationmanager.getBestProvider(cr, true);
 Location location = locationmanager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

 locationmanager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 200, 0, (LocationListener) this);




}






@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

     mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng((new        LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()))));


     CircleOptions circleOptions = new CircleOptions()
    .center(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));




          double bacons = Double.parseDouble(lengthString);

          if (bacons >=0) {

      double radi = bacons * 0.3048;
    circleOptions.radius(radi); // In meters
    circleOptions.fillColor(0xffff0000);
    circleOptions.strokeWidth(0);
    mMap.addCircle(circleOptions); 
          } else { 

        double radi = 20 * 0.3048;
        circleOptions.radius(radi); // In meters
        circleOptions.fillColor(0xffff0000);
        circleOptions.strokeWidth(0);

        mMap.addCircle(circleOptions); }












}
```

logcat

```
 07-24 11:23:45.021: I/dalvikvm(18121): Debugger is active
  07-24 11:23:45.211: I/System.out(18121): Debugger has connected
  07-24 11:23:45.211: I/System.out(18121): waiting for debugger to settle...
  07-24 11:23:45.411: I/System.out(18121): waiting for debugger to settle...
  07-24 11:23:45.622: I/System.out(18121): waiting for debugger to settle...
 07-24 11:23:45.822: I/System.out(18121): waiting for debugger to settle...
 07-24 11:23:46.022: I/System.out(18121): waiting for debugger to settle...
  07-24 11:23:46.222: I/System.out(18121): waiting for debugger to settle...
 07-24 11:23:46.432: I/System.out(18121): debugger has settled (1318)
 07-24 11:23:46.783: D/libEGL(18121): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_adreno200.so
 07-24 11:23:46.783: D/libEGL(18121): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno200.so
 07-24 11:23:46.783: D/libEGL(18121): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno200.so
 07-24 11:23:46.783: I/Adreno200-EGL(18121): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:265>: EGL 1.4   QUALCOMM build:  (CL3579225)
 07-24 11:23:46.783: I/Adreno200-EGL(18121): Build Date: 04/22/13 Mon
 07-24 11:23:46.783: I/Adreno200-EGL(18121): Local Branch: adreno_sba_20130419
 07-24 11:23:46.783: I/Adreno200-EGL(18121): Remote Branch: 
 07-24 11:23:46.783: I/Adreno200-EGL(18121): Local Patches: 
07-24 11:23:46.783: I/Adreno200-EGL(18121): Reconstruct Branch: 
 07-24 11:23:46.823: D/OpenGLRenderer(18121): Enabling debug mode 0
 07-24 11:23:52.739: D/GestureDetector(18121): [Surface Touch Event] mSweepDown False,  mLRSDCnt : -1 mTouchCnt : 4 mFalseSizeCnt:0
 07-24 11:23:53.920: D/AbsListView(18121): Get MotionRecognitionManager
 07-24 11:23:53.960: D/AbsListView(18121): onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 8
 07-24 11:23:53.960: D/AbsListView(18121): unregisterIRListener() is called 
07-24 11:23:53.970: D/AbsListView(18121): onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 8
 07-24 11:23:53.970: D/AbsListView(18121): unregisterIRListener() is called 
 07-24 11:23:53.980: D/dalvikvm(18121): GC_CONCURRENT freed 838K, 10% free 17854K/19680K, paused 4ms+4ms, total 41ms
 07-24 11:23:54.110: D/AbsListView(18121): onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 0
 07-24 11:23:54.110: D/AbsListView(18121): unregisterIRListener() is called 
 07-24 11:23:54.500: D/dalvikvm(18121): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 187K, 9% free 17909K/19680K, paused 27ms, total 27ms
 07-24 11:23:54.500: I/dalvikvm-heap(18121): Grow heap (frag case) to 18.505MB for 60496-byte allocation
 07-24 11:23:54.530: D/dalvikvm(18121): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 9% free 17967K/19740K, paused 23ms, total 23ms
 07-24 11:23:54.590: D/dalvikvm(18121): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 139K, 9% free 18210K/19980K, paused 18ms, total 18ms
 07-24 11:23:54.921: D/AbsListView(18121): onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 4
 07-24 11:23:54.921: D/AbsListView(18121): unregisterIRListener() is called 
 07-24 11:23:54.941: D/AbsListView(18121): onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 0
 07-24 11:23:54.941: D/AbsListView(18121): unregisterIRListener() is called 
 07-24 11:23:55.021: D/AbsListView(18121): unregisterIRListener() is called 
 07-24 11:23:55.551: D/dalvikvm(18121): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1664K, 14% free 18427K/21228K, paused 35ms, total 35ms
  07-24 11:23:55.631: D/AbsListView(18121): unregisterIRListener() is called 
   07-24 11:23:56.562: D/dalvikvm(18121): GC_CONCURRENT freed 332K, 13% free 18540K/21228K, paused 4ms+4ms, total 30ms
  07-24 11:23:56.562: D/dalvikvm(18121): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 22ms
   07-24 11:23:56.863: D/dalvikvm(18121): GC_CONCURRENT freed 269K, 12% free 18803K/21228K, paused 3ms+4ms, total 26ms
   07-24 11:23:59.555: D/dalvikvm(18121): GC_CONCURRENT freed 521K, 12% free 18848K/21228K, paused 4ms+5ms, total 31ms
  07-24 11:24:03.019: D/dalvikvm(18121): GC_CONCURRENT freed 562K, 12% free 18868K/21228K, paused 4ms+6ms, total 50ms
 07-24 11:24:04.120: D/dalvikvm(18121): threadid=1: still suspended after undo (sc=1 dc=1)
 07-24 11:24:04.140: D/dalvikvm(18121): threadid=1: still suspended after undo (sc=1 dc=1)
  07-24 11:24:04.140: D/dalvikvm(18121): GC_CONCURRENT freed 332K, 10% free 19152K/21228K, paused 3ms+5ms, total 29ms
  07-24 11:24:04.690: D/dalvikvm(18121): threadid=1: still suspended after undo (sc=1 dc=1)
 07-24 11:24:04.690: D/dalvikvm(18121): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 453K, 10% free 19301K/21228K, paused 22ms, total 22ms
07-24 11:24:04.700: I/dalvikvm-heap(18121): Grow heap (frag case) to 20.307MB for 524304-byte allocation
 07-24 11:24:04.720: D/dalvikvm(18121): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 136K, 10% free 19676K/21744K, paused 22ms, total 22ms
07-24 11:24:04.720: D/dalvikvm(18121): threadid=1: still suspended after undo (sc=1 dc=1)
 07-24 11:24:05.131: D/dalvikvm(18121): threadid=1: still suspended after undo (sc=1 dc=1)
 07-24 11:24:05.131: D/dalvikvm(18121): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 564K, 12% free 19180K/21744K, paused 27ms, total 28ms
 07-24 11:24:05.131: I/dalvikvm-heap(18121): Grow heap (frag case) to 20.689MB for 1048592-byte allocation
 07-24 11:24:05.151: D/dalvikvm(18121): threadid=1: still suspended after undo (sc=1 dc=1)
  07-24 11:24:05.151: D/dalvikvm(18121): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1K, 12% free 20203K/22772K, paused 23ms, total 23ms
```

Comment: post the stack trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are initializing outside `onCreate`. Move your initialization of edittext inside `onCreate`.

```
EditText length;
String lengthString;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
length = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1); 
....// rest of the code
}
```

Also get the text on button click

```
 lengthString = length.getText().toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

`findViewById` needs the current hiearchy of views to be created in order to work, so you can call

```
EditText length = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1); 
String lengthString = length.getText().toString();
```

only after `setContentView`

Comment: @Raghunandan   Ok. Thanks.

It now runs until the map loads and then suspends.

I will post the edited code above.

Comment: Is what I have above what you mean?

Comment: yes it is, but you posted the wrong portion. You have to post the part  that talks about the crash of your application

Comment: thanks. I have updated it. The app runs, but freezes on the screen and then the debug perspective opens on my computer, but the app doesn't actually terminate.

Comment: does your application crash ?

Comment: It did initially before I made the changes you recommended above. Now it just sits on the map and the map is frozen. It isn't drawing the circles. And the debug perspective comes up on my computer.

Comment: but do you set some brakpoints ? Why are you launch your application in debug mode ?

Comment: Yes it crashes when not being debugged.

Comment: why is it so difficult to post the crashlog (stacktrace )?

Comment: I posted the stacktrace above. It doesn't crash when the phone is connected to the debugger. Only when the usb cable is physically unhooked. Sorry. How would I display a stacktrace with a crash if it only happens disconnected?